# Move image by button on Xcode 8

Tags: swift, image, animation, uiimageview

```js
import UIKit

class Level2ViewController: UIViewController {

    var image = UIImage(named: "ballon.png")

        
    var imageView = UIImageView(image: "ballon") //initialize properly, this is just for reference
    
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
       
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.imageView.frame.origin.x += 50
        }, completion: nil)
    
       
}
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
   
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

[image: the code]

I'm using swift 3 Xcode 8 with a single view application. My problem is that I want to make an image move right using a button. A lot of the videos and other questions about this do not work with Xcode 8, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
var imageView = UIImageView() //initialize properly, this is just for reference

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        imageView.frame.origin.x -= 50
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

For initializing your image you should do something like this:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "yourImageName.png")

var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

Keep in mind that the photo you are using should be imported into Xcode, and you need to make sure the name exactly matches for the initialization of `image`

Comment: awesome! how can I make it faster though

Comment: The animation duration is currently 0.1 seconds. You can just adjust that number to your liking

Comment: If you want it to go so fast that it doesn't animate at all, you can also just directly edit the frame without the animation.

Comment: sorry, I'm kind of new so can you tell me how to initialize my image?

Comment: @QUINN Just by using the `imageView.frame.origin.x -= 50` line

Comment: what would happen if I changed the value of 50 in -=50 to 100?

Comment: @QUINN Think about the screen in terms of a cartesian plane. The origin of the frame are coordinates on that plane. When you alter the x coordinate by -50, the frame moves 50 units to the left. Thus, when it is -100, the frame will move 100 units to the left. In this case, units represent pixels (more or less).

Comment: Why don't you stop and consider that for a second. It's not hard.

Comment: origin.y is the answer

Comment: @QUINN Nope. It would be this: `imageView.frame.origin.x += 50`

Comment: I really need help on making my mage move to the right at a fast pace. the things that you said to try and help to make the image move faster didn't work

Comment: I suggest simply using the animation, just with a very small value for "withDuration:"

Comment: now the image is not moving. Do you need a gray dot next to the "var image"?

Comment: the image is still moving left even with the +=.

Comment: No, incrementing the x variable will cause it to move right, please check your code.

Comment: the image still isn't moving and I pasted my code above.

Comment: Make sure it is in the animation, otherwise it won't move.

Comment: Your code looks correct, so try and think what you changed between now and when it worked.

Comment: the only thing that I changed was that I added in "var image = UIImage(named: "yourImageName.png")"